# PHP get array value if it has a certain string from another array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have multiple files that I am trying to consolidate into 1 single file. Each file has something similar to this:

```
var nr = ['1.02.3.1','1.02.3.4'];
var p = [{"ip":"1.02.3.1","parents":["1.02.3.0","1.1.2.2"},{"ip":"1.04.1.1","parents":["1.1.30.0","1.15.2.2"}];
```

Keep in mind, I am trying to parsing the information as text for now.

Different files have different IPs, (IPs being the values within the lists. I consolidate 2 files at a time. For the nr array, it's easy. All I did was strip the unnecessary data to leave me with 
'1.02.3.1','1.02.3.4'
then I exploded the string into an array. I merge the array with the other file's array, take out duplicates, implode the data, add the "var nr =[" and "];"

I am having trouble with the next part. I want to cross check "p" with "nr". With the consolidated "nr" array. If any of the values of "nr" match the ip of "p, then save write the ip to a new array called "nrp" and save the list of parents from that ip to the consolidated "p" array. Also, I want to delete the ip and parent ips that are not listed by "nr".

For example, I will represent ip as letters

File A:

```
var nr = ['A','B','C'];
var p = [{"ip":"A","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"B","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"C","parents":["K","L","M"]} ];
```

File B:

```
var nr = ['A','C','D'];
var p = [{"ip":"A","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"D","parents":["N","O","P"]},{"ip":"C","parents":["K","L","M"]} ];
```

File consolidate:

```
var nr = ['A','B','C','D'];
var p = [{"ip":"A","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"B","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"D","parents":["N","O","P"]},{"ip":"C","parents":["K","L","M"]}];
var nrp = ['J','K','L','N','O','P','M'];
```

My approach so far:
This is after I have the data in arrays.

```
$consolidatedNR = ['A','B','C','D'];
$consolidatedP = [{"ip":"A","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"B","parents":["J","K","L"]},{"ip":"D","parents":["N","O","P"]},{"ip":"C","parents":["K","L","M"]}];

foreach($consolidatedP as $key5 => &$string5){
            foreach($consolidatedNR as $key2 => &$ip){
                if($string5 contains "'ip':$ip"){
                    array_push($content4, $ip);
                }
                else{
                    unset($consolidatedP[$key5]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I see JavaScript in this.

Comment: That is correct, but I am parsing it as a text file. If you have any alternatives or advice please share.

Comment: If you have it as string, you could use the function `json_decode` to make it php array/object (instead of str), si it's easier to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrays that you have are acceptable JSON formats. You can remove the JavaScript assignments from the string, explode the string into two lines and then use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to convert the lines into PHP arrays.

This should work for you:

**Edit**: I've edited and tested this code.

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOF
var nr = ['1.02.3.1','1.02.3.4'];
var p = [{"ip":"1.02.3.1","parents":["1.02.3.0","1.1.2.2"]},{"ip":"1.04.1.1","parents":["1.1.30.0","1.15.2.2"]}];
EOF;

$str = str_replace(array("var nr = ", "var p = ", ";"), "", $str);
$str = str_replace("'", "\"", $str);
$str = explode("\n", $str);

$parents_list = array();
$ip_list = array();

$nr = json_decode($str[0], true);
$p = json_decode($str[1], true);
echo "<pre>";
foreach($p as $p_list) {
    if(in_array($p_list['ip'], $nr)) {
        array_push($ip_list, $p_list['ip']);
        $parents_list = array_merge($p_list['parents'], $parents_list);
    }
}

echo "Parents list:<pre>";
print_r($parents_list);
echo "</pre>IP list:<pre>";
print_r($ip_list);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: any idea how I would merge the $p_list to another $p_list?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean